# cron reboot after script

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, reboot

I want a daily backup, update and reboot on my raspberry pi (Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) using a `cron job`.

So with `root` I use `crontab -e` and set the following jobs:

`30 3 * * * /mnt/usb/backup/scripts/backup_daily.sh
00 3 * * * apt-get update`

To update and backup a couple folders every day between 3am and 3:30.

Now after this I want to reboot the system. I know I can do something like

`0 4 * * * reboot now`

But I'm afraid that maybe my backup is still doing it's thing. Is there a way I can add a reboot job after my script has successfully finished?

Answer (score 0):

At the last line of the backup_daily.sh put the reboot command.
and don't do it from cron.